# Problema en la línea 6 con la session de usuario

Tags: php, postgresql

Adjunto el código:

```
<?php
    include_once "validacion.php"; 
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['usuario'] == true){
        header('Location:index2.php');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login de prueba</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <label>Nombre de usuario:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" required="">
            <br>
            <label>ContraseÃ±a:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" required="">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="enviado" value="Ingresar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Adjunto el código del que se supone es el validador:

```
<?php
    include("conexion.php");
    $conexion = new Conn();
    if(isset($_POST['enviado'])){
        $usuario = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        if(empty($usuario) || empty($pass)){
            echo '<script>alert("No puedes ingresar valores nulos");</script>';
        }else{
            $sql =  "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE username =  :username  AND password = :password";
            $consulta = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            $consulta->execute(array('username' => $usuario, 'password' => $pass));
            $count = $consulta->rowCount();
            if($count){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = true;
                header('Location:index2.php');                  
            }else{
                echo "El usuario o contraseña no coincide"; 
            }
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['cerrarSesion'])){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = false;
        header('Location:index.php');
    }
?>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por la atención brindada.

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor describir mejor el problema? Realmente el título de la pregunta no ayuda mucho: *problema con la línea 6 con la session de usuario* ... ¿Cuál es el problema y cuál es la línea 6?

Comment: Estimado, sería posible que muestres el error que te sale, por lo que veo en tu código, creería que te sale un error de "session" por lo que la estás iniciando dos veces. ----- En esta parte de aquí [![Tu primer adjunto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cGu4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cGu4.png) Tu estás incluyendo un archivo php, Es el segundo código que pasaste? o es otro archivo?

Comment: Si perdona por eso, seré más conciso sobre mi problematica, a la hora de abrir mi proyecto en el navegador me sale un error que me notifica que en la línea 6 del primer trozo de código mostrado  "Undefined index:usuario in (ruta de mi archivo) on line 6"

Comment: Si perdona por eso, seré más conciso sobre mi problematica, a la hora de abrir mi proyecto en el navegador me sale un error que me notifica que en la línea 6 del primer trozo de código mostrado "Undefined index:usuario in (ruta de mi archivo) on line 6".

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia de antemano dado a que no sé en que momento inicio dos sesiones y me gustaría que me pudieras explicarlo sino te molesta.

Comment: Voy a empezar a editar mi comentario para poder agregar screenshots.

Comment: Mira el archivo que incluí en esa línea es uno que tiene como finalidad validar los campos y si sucede redireccionar a la persona hacia la siguiente vista

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no hay muchos antecedentes del trace del error y de que el código se ve coherente, es posible que sea por una condición de borde que gatillo el error, un consejo es que la instrucción session_start() sea lo primero en ejecutar, primero para evitar problemas de confusión en tu implementación de la validación de sesión y será mas ordenado.

Lo segundo es que una vez que validas el usuario en tu archivo "validacion.php" inicias la sesión para luego gatillar una redirección al archivo index2.php, es importante que luego de la instrucción header("Location:xxx") pongas un exit para que se corte la ejecución del script, porque php no redireccionará hasta que termine de ejecutar todas las instrucciones, básicamente lo que digo es que adiciones exit() de la siguiente manera

```
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = true;
        header('Location:index2.php');
        exit();
```

Con esto seguramente se solucionará el problema puntual de tu código

saludos y espero que sea de ayuda

Comment: Primero que todo gracias, he Implemente tal cual como lo muestra tu ejemplo y uso el exit() más no ha resultado funcionar, ¿tienes alguna otra idea sobre que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Si mira, según veo en una respuesta hay una especificación del error  "Undefined index:usuario in (ruta de mi archivo) on line 6" imagino que la **ruta de mi archivo** hace referencia al archivo el cual tiene el formulario, si es así es que estas llamando al atributo de una sesión que está vacía , lo correcto para validar ese if puede ser de la siguiente forma:


if ( isset($_SESSION['usuario'])  &&  $_SESSION['usuario'] == true){
        header('Location:index2.php');
        exit();
}

Comment: Muchas gracias, es tan lógico y simple que ni lo noté, de nuevo gracias por tu ayuda.